# Parsing error with dependent template type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Is the following code in accordance with the C++20 standard? Or, should it be rejected due to some syntax error? All 3 compilers (Clang, GCC, and MSVC) seem to reject it.

```cpp
template<typename...>
struct n {
    template<typename>
    struct b {
        template<typename>
        struct p {};
    };
    template<typename T>
    struct d : b<T>::template p<T> {};
    template<typename T>
    d(b<int>::template p<T>) -> d<T>;
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr auto v = d{b<int>::template p<T>{}};
};
inline constexpr auto w = n{}.v<int>;
```

When removing the template-head of type `n`, all compilers accept the code. Why does this matter? What does the standard have to say about the way the code should be processed based on whether `n` is templated?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W49aGe7fn)

---

Clang's error message:

```cpp
<source>:11:15: error: 'template' keyword not permitted here
   11 |     d(b<int>::template p<T>) -> d<T>;
      |               ^~~~~~~~
<source>:11:24: error: member 'p' declared as a template
   10 |     template<typename T>
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   11 |     d(b<int>::template p<T>) -> d<T>;
      |                        ^
<source>:11:29: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
   11 |     d(b<int>::template p<T>) -> d<T>;
      |                             ^
      |                             ;
<source>:13:54: error: expected '}'
   13 |     static constexpr auto v = d{b<int>::template p<T>{}};
      |                                                      ^
<source>:13:32: note: to match this '{'
   13 |     static constexpr auto v = d{b<int>::template p<T>{}};
      |                                ^
<source>:13:27: error: declaration of variable 'v' with deduced type 
'const auto' requires an initializer
   13 |     static constexpr auto v = d{b<int>::template p<T>{}};
      |                           ^
<source>:13:27: error: declaration of variable 'v' with deduced type 
'const auto' requires an initializer
<source>:15:31: note: in instantiation of static data member 'n<>::v<int>'
requested here
   15 | inline constexpr auto w = n{}.v<int>;
      |                               ^
<source>:15:23: error: constexpr variable 'w' must be initialized by a
constant expression
   15 | inline constexpr auto w = n{}.v<int>;
      |                       ^   ~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:15:27: note: non-literal type 'auto' cannot be used in a constant
expression
   15 | inline constexpr auto w = n{}.v<int>;
      |                           ^
```

GCC's error message:

```cpp
<source>:13:32: error: missing template arguments before '{' token
   13 |     static constexpr auto v = d{b<int>::template p<T>{}};
      |                                ^
<source>:15:31: error: 'struct n<>' has no member named 'v'
   15 | inline constexpr auto w = n{}.v<int>;
      |                               ^
<source>:15:33: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
   15 | inline constexpr auto w = n{}.v<int>;
      |                                 ^~~
```

MSVC's error message:

```cpp
<source>(13): error C2760: syntax error: '{' was unexpected here; expected '}'
<source>(13): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(14): note: see reference to class template instantiation 
'n<<unnamed-symbol>...>' being compiled
```

---

As mentioned by HolyBlackCat, adding `typename` to `b<int>::template p<T>{}` makes the construction of `d` possible on GCC and MSVC. Clang still rejects the code because it seems to have an issue with the deduction guide, however.

This leaves me with the question whether  `typename` can be omitted from `d`'s deduction guide while still being compliant to the C++20 standard. MSVC also allows the omittance of `typename` when changing the curley braces to parentheses, but I presume this behavior to be non-compliant.

Comment: [Here](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#4) is a list of contexts where you can omit `typename`. Looks like the deduction guide parameters aren't there.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer)ing this is necessary, there's a simple explanation.

`b<int>` is a dependent type, it depends on the template parameters of `n`.

How is it dependent, you may ask? Because it can be specialized, e.g.:

```
template <>
template <>
struct n<int>::b<long> {};
```

If you prepend `typename` to `b<int>`, the code works... except Clang doesn't like the deduction guide, which perhaps should be a separate question.

```
<source>:11:5: error: deduction guide template contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced
   11 |     d(typename b<int>::template p<T>) -> d<T>;
      |     ^
```

Comment: MSVC seems to accept the construction of `d` with `p` without use of `typename` when changing `{}` to `()`. Is that behavior non-compliant with the C++20 standard? Which specific rule mandates this?

Comment: Why is `typename` necessary for `p` when constructing `d` but not when specifying `p` for `d`'s deduction guide? Which specific rule in the C++20 standard describes the difference in use of `typename` here?

Comment: @303 here you can find lots of details, I think also links to relevant parts of the standard https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/4117728